# Javascript: text selection including special characters

Tags: javascript, html, web, range, selection

I'm using this javascript code to grab the word immediately preceding the caret:

```
sel = window.getSelection()
var selectedRange = sel.getRangeAt(0);
sel.collapseToStart();
sel.modify("move", "backward", "word");
sel.modify("extend", "forward", "word");
```

This gets the word, even without trailing whitespace (ex. "word") but omits special characters on the end of the word (ex. instead of **"word:"** gets just **"word"**).

If I include the colon inside of a word, like "wo:rd", this gets all 5 characters.

I really need to get trailing special characters, though. How can I do this?

Comment: great question, I'm working on a solution - it seems that the output we would be looking for is a "selection" not a "range", we need to get the value of the modified selection, and then match a regex to the parent node's nodeValue like /value + [^A-Za-z0-9]/ig

Comment: `Selection.modify()` is inconcistently implemented between browsers and IE doesn't implement it all. An alternative is [Rangy's TextRange module](https://github.com/timdown/rangy/wiki/Text-Range-Module) (disclaimer: written by me) that does this stuff consistently across browsers and allows a regex that specifies what constitutes a word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, I apologize for the sloppiness of the example code but here it is: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iamwhitebox/o9najw69/)

```
var i = 0;

function getBeforeSelection() {
    var sel = window.getSelection(),
        selectedRange = sel.getRangeAt(0),
        sel2,
        res,
        finalValue,
        regexObj;

    sel.collapseToStart();
    sel.modify("move", "backward", "word");
    sel.modify("extend", "forward", "word");

    finalValue = sel.toString();

    regexObj = new RegExp(finalValue + '[^A-Za-z0-9\s\b]*');

    res = sel.focusNode.nodeValue.trim().match(regexObj);

    alert(res);

}

// added for sake of example, calls getBeforeSelection on double click 
// (when selection is made)
document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    i++;

    if (i > 1) {
        getBeforeSelection();
        i = 0;
    } 
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work in Firefox. `Selection.modify()` is inconsistently implemented between browsers.